# ¿Como puedo hacer un join entre dos documentos en MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

¿Como puedo hacer un join entre dos documentos en MongoDB?

**Teniendo esta relación en SQL**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer una consulta en MongoDB que sea análogo a el siguiente codigo SQL

```
SELECT Employee.Name, EmployeePhoto.IdEmployee
FROM Employee NATURAL JOIN EmployeePhoto
WHERE Employee.Name = "Pepito";
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola @Luis Miguel Baez,

Tienes dos opciones para realizar la relación entre Colecciones en MongoDB:

- Método 'populate' de [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).
- Método 'aggregate' de MongoDB con la etapa [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

El que te recomendaría es el método 'aggregate' de MongoDB ya que puedes tener mas funcionalidades como, por ejemplo, hacer una relación con mas de un campo del documento o filtrar la información de la colección que relacionas, etc.

Espero que esta información te haya ayudado a resolver tus dudas.

Un saludo